# How to determine Threading Model of given COM library?

Tags: .net, windows, com, model, multithreading

I have a COM library I should use in my ASP.NET MVC application. However I am unsure about its thread apartment model. How can I determine it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Determine the component's `CLSID` from the registry using this key:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\{component's progid}\CLSID
```

Then lookup the `ThreadingModel` using this registry key

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{component's clsid}\InprocServer32\ThreadingModel
```

Answer (score 3):

The [OLE/COM Object Viewer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms688269%28VS.85%29.aspx) also shows the threading model for components.