# Reuse an object in multiple threads

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, object

I have a situation where I'd like to reuse an object in multiple threads.  It is a com object, a terminal emulator.  As I proceed through a loop processing a report, as I find certain conditions I start a new thread which is pulling some information in another terminal emulator session and adding it to a collection.  It is this terminal emulator I'd like to reuse in multiple threads rather than create a new object each time.  I've tried declaring it as a static object, no go, but that wasn't suprising.  I've tried creating it in the original thread and accessing it using synclock, which doesn't seem to work well either.  I keep getting an "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" error.  Trying to look it up now, but I'm not sure if I can do what I'm trying to do or not.  I don't think invoke is an option here, so I'm not sure if this will work as written...

Ok, by request (and likely good practice for asking questions anyway) here is my code where I was attempting to use static... I've got quite a bit going on in the real code, so I've tried to trim this down to only the relevant portions.

```
Imports System.Threading
Imports System.Threading.Tasks
Imports Reflection

Public Class optionsApplication

Private Sub parseReport

    Dim openOrderCheckTasks As Task

    Dim intCounter As Integer

    Dim terminal As Reflection.Session 'This is one example of the terminal emulator

    For intCounter = 1 to 24

        'Do some things to get data from the terminal screen

        openOrderCheckTasks = Task.Factory.StartNew(Sub() openOrderCheck(accountNum, identifier))

    Next intCounter

End Sub


Private Sub openOrderCheck

    Static openCheckTerminal As Reflection.Session
    If some openCheckTerminal is nothing then
                       openCheckTerminal = New Reflection.Session
                       formatTerminal(openCheckTerminal)  <
    End If

    SyncLock openCheckTerminal

        'Do stuff here to get data and add to a collection

    End Synclock

End Sub

End Class
```

And I can confirm that when attempting to use static I am getting the object reference not set to an instance of an object message.

I think this is starting to become a little more clear.  It seems like what happens is the second time a thread tries to use this object, synclock seems to stop the progress of the first thread and the second can't find the object.  I can see the terminal stopping mid way through the code of the first thread, and the error is occuring when the second tries to begin.  I'm wondering if this is a problem with this particular object... I think I may have to find a way to see if the first thread completed before begining the second...

Actually, I was mistaken... for some reason the object is disapearing from the second thread in the middle of the the thread after synclock.  This doesn't seem to make any sense.  Nothing else is trying to touch that object.  It performs one command, and then stops.  I'm begining to think the issue may be with the com object itself.  If anyone is curious, this is the Attachmate Reflections Terminal emulator.

EDIT:  Going to add the first half of the sub that loses the object in full detail to see if it might be helpfull.

```
Private Sub openOrderCheck(ByVal accountNum As String, ByVal quantity As String, ByVal optionSeries As String, ByVal openCheckTerminal As Reflection.Session)

    Dim intCounter As Integer

    Dim omsMessage As String
    Dim openOrderData(2) As String

    Debug.Print("Made it here...")
    SyncLock openCheckTerminal
        If openCheckTerminal.GetDisplayText(23, 2, 5) <> "READY" Then
            terminalFormat(openCheckTerminal)
        End If
        With openCheckTerminal
            .TransmitANSI("OMS")
            .TransmitTerminalKey(rcIBMEnterKey)
            .WaitForEvent(rcNewHostScreen, "10", "", 1, 1)
            .WaitForEvent(rcKbdEnabled, "10", "0", 1, 1)
            .TransmitANSI("5")
            .TransmitTerminalKey(rcIBMEnterKey)
            .WaitForEvent(rcNewHostScreen, "10", "", 1, 1)
            .WaitForEvent(rcKbdEnabled, "10", "0", 1, 1)
            For intCounter = 1 To 7
                .TransmitTerminalKey(rcIBMTabKey)
            Next intCounter
            .TransmitANSI(accountNum)
            .TransmitTerminalKey(rcIBMTabKey)
            .TransmitANSI(optionSeries)
            .TransmitTerminalKey(rcIBMTabKey)
            .TransmitTerminalKey(rcIBMTabKey)
            .TransmitTerminalKey(rcIBMTabKey)
            .TransmitANSI("Y")
            .TransmitTerminalKey(rcIBMEnterKey)
            .WaitForEvent(rcNewHostScreen, "10", "", 1, 1)
            .WaitForEvent(rcKbdEnabled, "10", "0", 1, 1)
            omsMessage = .GetDisplayText(24, 23, 15)
            openOrderData(0) = optionSeries
            openOrderData(1) = .GetDisplayText(13, 93, 7)
            openOrderData(2) = .GetDisplayText(13, 82, 8)
            .TransmitTerminalKey(rcIBMF3Key)
            .WaitForEvent(rcNewHostScreen, "10", "", 1, 1)
            .WaitForEvent(rcKbdEnabled, "10", "0", 1, 1)
        End With
    End SyncLock
```

Comment: Ok, I'll switch back to the static method, exactly what I was thinking, post some code, and verify the error.  I believe it was giving me the same error.  For the reocord, I got it to work by passing the object to the threads using synclock, but this slows down the main thread which is less than desireable.  Give me a moment to let this test run its course, and I'll put some more up there.

Comment: Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7930627/com-multi-threading-support

Comment: @Crono Yes, I believe the first answer to that question fits my problem perfectly.  I'm not sure I'm up to doing a message pump... but I'm sure I could figure it out.  Looks as though I'll have to set this one up to opperate a little differently.  Thank you so much for your insight and cueing me onto this question and answer, I think you just saved me a lot of time.

Comment: No problem man, I wish you luck on this one. Never tried that myself. :)

Comment: @Crono I enjoy learning new techniques... the jury is still out on whether or not I should try it.  The application would be faster overall if I went ahead with the message pumping, but maybe not by enough to make it worth it.  I'm reading up on it now, but if I go that route it will just be me being stubborn about it and doing it to learn it.  Again, thanks.  This one was truly perplexing.